# Choosing the right converter

Tags: power, battery

I'm having trouble calculating the right converter to buy in order to power a Raspberry 2 from batteries.

I'm using 6 batteries (6x1.5V) so I guess I'll need to get an UBEC Converter like [this one](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1385). All my thoughts are based on [this tutorial](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/02/running-a-raspberry-pi-from-6-aa-batteries/).
The batteries will also power two DC motors.

The Raspberry will be used for basic operations, to control the motors. There will be a wifi dongle connected, and an external usb camera.

Is such an converter going to be enough?

Comment: "Is such an converter going to be enough?".  The converter will be enough to supply 2-3 amps at 5V continuously.  If your kit takes less than that it will be enough.  if your kit takes more than that it will not be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you found looks good. It requires >= 6V input, which your batteries will provide even close to the end of their life.

For the Pi 2's current consumption, [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/introducing-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b?view=all) estimates 650 mA (with a WiFi dongle and heavy computation). For the camera, the USB standard allows any device to draw at most 500 mA. The converter you found is specified for 3A, which is sufficient with a nice margin.

One thing to consider though is how well the Pi handles powering devices through the USB ports. With the original Pi:s, it's often recommended to use a powered USB hub if the devices draw significant current.